# Program returns "NumberNode" object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

No matter what I try, when I reference the "NumberNode" (custom class) object, with a parameter, like this: "return NumberNode(tok)", the compiler returns an error. I've done this with classes already and it worked, i don't understand why it fails this time. Help? Here's some code:

```
class NumberNode:
    def __init__(self, tok):
        self.tok = tok

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.tok}'

class AnotherClass:
    def factor(self):
        tok = self.current_tok

        if tok.type in (TT_INT, TT_FLOAT):
            self.advance()
            return NumberNode(tok)
```

Comment: I doubt if you have reassigned `NumberNode` to something else. Please share a snippet that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code above does. "return NumberNode(tok)" outputs the error message. I don't think NumberNode is reassigned anywhere else